# Magento 2 New Install on WAMP Can't Login to Admin

Tags: magento2

I've installed Magento 2 on WAMP and the admin username/password page displays okay. However, after clicking login chrome shows a "This site can’t be reached, The connection was reset." message.

1. Same install process on LAMP server works okay.
2. Have confirmed that the admin account is enabled and password is okay. Saw posts about there being a Magento 2 setup bug related to passwords.
3. Have created a new admin user via cli but get the same result.
4. Tried changing the admin url via cli but get the same result.
5. Have turned off caching and deleted all files in var/cache.
6. Same behavior in other browsers.
7. Complete re-install from scratch.
8. Reboot PC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying many suggestions (including 127.0.0.1 suggestion above), only upgrading the PHP version resolved this issue. Confirmed working with Magento version 2.1.6.

Upgraded PHP from 5.6.19 to 7.0.4.

Interestingly, on PHP 5.6.19 the dashboard url /admin/admin/dashboard/index/ gives the "This site can't be reached" error but other urls work okay e.g. /admin/admin/system_config/

Answer (score 5):

Hope this will help you

you can try this:

> php bin\magento setup:static-content:deploy

in your CLI. clear cache and try again.

Comment: Ran the following to get around memory error. Did not resolve this issue.
php -dmemory_limit=2G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `localhost` as your base URL? in Chrome it should be 127.0.0.1 otherwise use Firefox.

Comment: I use local urls like this: http://local.magento207.com/ and have had no problems like this on Magento 1.x.

Comment: You have to change the host name from localhost to 127.0.0.1 if you want to see the admin section in chrome. In your database search for the table "core_config_data" search for localhost value and change it to 127.0.0.1